# How to filter a dictionary by any key and return all keys-values attributes?

Tags: python, json, dictionary

I have a dictionary whose keys and values are strings. I would like to filter the dictionary by some **key = value** and I would get as result all information about that filter.

For example:

I have a dictionary of data, say:

```
data = 
{
    "events": 
    [
        {
            "start_date": {
                "year": "2007",
                "month": "03"
            },
            "end_date": {
                "year": "2008",
                "month": "09"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": "https://someurl_001.com",
                "credit": "Some Credit 001"
            },
            "text": {
                "headline": "Some Headline 001",
                "text": "Some Text 001"
            },
            "tags": {
                "tag1": "orange",
                "tag2": "banana"
            }
        },
        {
            "start_date": {
                "year": "2007",
                "month": "06"
            },
            "end_date": {
                "year": "2008",
                "month": "02"
            },
            "media": {
                "url": "https://someurl_002.com"
            },
            "text": {
                "headline": "Some Headline 002",
                "text": "Some Text 002"
            },
            "tags": {
                "tag1": "orange",
                "tag2": "lemon"
            }
        },
    ]
}
```

I wold like do something like:

```
some_function("year" = "2007", "month" = "03")
```

Output:
Only dict that has this filter:

```
"events": [
    {
        "start_date": {
            "year": "2007",
            "month": "03"
        },
        "end_date": {
            "year": "2008",
            "month": "09"
        },
        "media": {
            "url": "https://someurl_001.com",
            "credit": "Some Credit 001"
        },
        "text": {
            "headline": "Some Headline 001",
            "text": "Some Text 001"
        },
        "tags": {
            "tag1": "orange",
            "tag2": "banana"
        }
    }
]
```

or

```
some_function("tag1" = "orange")
```

OUTPUT:

All dict because "tag1" : "orange" was in all my sample.

Comment: That's not proper syntax for calling a function. You can use `some_function(year = "2007")`. Then you can use `**kwargs` in the function definition to get all the keyword arguments as a dictionary. Then use this dictionary in your filtering.

Comment: Could you add more context? It can be done with python dict but with such nested dictionary it's not easy approach, I would recommend you to use another format e.g. xml, but need to know bigger picture to advice.

Comment: @kosciej16, I have a json file and I would like to use them as a "database", filtering some attribute, and returning all content for that filter to show. I'm trying to filter this json : [link]http://timeline.knightlab.com/docs/json-format.html#json-era  but not all data, just a subset of them.